React Pagination and useEffect depencency logic
Basically, i have a function that fetches the filtered datas and that is fetchDataFromMain function.
useEffect(() => {
  setHasMorePage(true);
  setPage(1);
  setFilteredEvents([]);
}, [selectedDate, selectedCategory, selectedProvince]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (page === 4) {
    setHasMorePage(false);
  } else {
    setHasMorePage(true)
  }

  if ((page <= 4 && hasMorePage)) {
    console.log("useeffect worked", page)
    fetchDataFromMain();
  } 
}, [page, selectedDate, selectedCategory, selectedProvince])

i have complete all 4 pages. and every pages has 20 datas. when page increases, the data will also compounds 20*2 in the back-end and sends it to client. But, whenever i increase the page with scrolling down and change a filter, the useEffect work twice, and sends two fetch request to the back-end because the page in the condition i check if page smaller and equals to 4, and also even if i make hasMorePage false, it fetch the request anyways.
My problem is, I don't want to fetch the data twice, but i can't find a solution. Does anyone have any idea how can i solve this issue?

Do you experience this only on local development or also with your deployed application?
I'm asking this because it could be related to React.StrictMode wrapping your application, which will cause your effects to run always twice. But only for local development.

@ViktorLuft Yes, i was also encountered that problem too and deleted the StrictMode. everyone experiencing the same issue should check if the parent component is wrapped with React StrictMode component because it will make your useEffects run twice.  Thanks.

This is because hasMorePage has not yet become false even if you're setting it to false and will become false in the next render cycle.
You can probably move this if condition to another useEffect and see if that helps
if ((page <= 4 && hasMorePage)) {
  console.log("useeffect worked", page)
  fetchDataFromMain();
} 

